# Express + Typescript: Adding values in router.param

Tags: typescript, express

The [Express 4.x](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.param) API gives this example for how to use `Router.param`:

```js
router.param('user', function (req, res, next, id) {
  // try to get the user details from the User model and attach it to the request object
  User.find(id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      next(err)
    } else if (user) {
      req.user = user
      next()
    } else {
      next(new Error('failed to load user'))
    }
  })
})
```

What's the best way to get this working with TypeScript? The line `req.user = user` will fail in the given example, since the `express.Request` object does not have a `user` property.

And once that's working, how do you use it in a later `router.get` call?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new file called `custom.d.ts`.

You can then add properties to the Express.Request interface like this:

```
declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
        myNewProperty?: string
    }
}
```

This will then allow you to do stuff like this:

```
app.param('user', function(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction, id: string) {
    User.find(id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        } else if (user) {
            req.user = user;
            next();
        } else {
            next(new Error('failed to load user'));
        }
    });
});
```

You can prevent the property from being added to every request by creating a new interface that extends the `Request` interface. You can then use the new interface in the express callback function like this:

```
interface RequestButCooler extends Request {
  user?: string;
}

app.param('user', function(req: RequestButCooler , res: Response, next: NextFunction, id: string) {
    // req.user is now available only here
});
```

Comment: Seems like an alright way to go, but this would add the property to every request from there on, right? It might just be a limitation of how express evolved without TypeScript

Comment: edit - I forgot the first line of the 2nd code block. Yeah it will add whatever user is to every request to "/user". However if you have 2 seperate routes which both point to "/user" it will still be called only once.